# Unable to write to secondary firebase database but works with [DEFAULT] Db

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have two databases in firebase project currently. One [DEFAULT] and other a secondary database. Both these databases have exactly same rule and exactly same data( I exported data from [DEFAULT] db and imported to secondary)

But the problem is I am able to read/write to [DEFAULT] database but I'm unable to write in secondary db.

If I have a [DEFAULT] db name "my-proj-r4t5" and secondary db name "my-proj-r4t5-c6v7" then the secondary database url will be "https://my-proj-r4t5-c6v7.firebaseio.com/.

I used following FirebaseOptions config to access secondary db,

```
    var secondApp: FirebaseApp
    val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("APP ID")
            .setApiKey(" API KEY HERE")
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://my-proj-r4t5-c6v7.firebaseio.com/")
            .setProjectId("my-proj-r4t5")
            .build()
    try {
        secondApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options, "my-proj-r4t5-c6v7")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        secondApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance("my-proj-r4t5-c6v7")
    }

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(secondApp).getReference()
```

- If I'm missing out on any thing in above setup please let me know
- I also have a confusion with database url, I might be supplying a wrong url. If you find something wrong in this url please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, just instantiate the DatabaseReference like below

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://my-proj-r4t5-c6v7.firebaseio.com/").getReference()
```

and it will work.